# How to make image cube for 3d convolution with file path

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Recently, I am studying 3d convolution for video image processing with tensorflow.

I make model with tutorial blog. But i want to make my custom dataset. My input image's shape is (128,128,3) and i want to make image cube(128,128,100,3). I use tensorflow.data.dataset and I tried to create a map function by recalling my memories I used for 2d convolution. I want to image cube using path that consist of (Number of image cube, 100) with tf.data.dataset map function because of running out of memory when using NumPy.

I tried to use code like the following

```
def load_image(path):
    images = []
    for i, p in enumerate(path):
        image_string = tf.io.read_file(p)
        image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(p, channels=3)
        image = tf.reshape(image, [128,128,1,3])
        image = image / 255
        images.append(image)
    image_block = tf.concat(images, axis=2)
    return image_block

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(total_files) # shape (1077,100)
train_data = train_data.map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

But have error that tensor's shape changes. And i also use tf.Variable using .assign but have similar error.

How to make 3d convolution's input image cube with path??? I use tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: Could you show full error message?

Comment: peratorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you cannnot iterate over tensor like `for x in tensor`. In that case you can for example iterate over range and get value by index like

```
for x in range(tf.shape(tensor)[0]):
   y = tensor[x]
```

Comment: When you do `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(total_files)` you are creating dataset containing tensors. So when you do `train_data.map()` you are passing tensor as parameter.

Comment: Thank you!! I did what you said and it runs without errors!!